# When joining a CSV file to a Vector layer on QGIS, the Graduate style can't be classified

Tags: qgis, vector, style, attribute-joins

I have a CSV file with GEOID, GEO.id2, and then 5 calculated values. I am trying to make a map using the graduated style with my shapefile.

I have made a CSVT file w/ "String","String","Real","Real","Real","Real","Real"
Also, I have tried adding the CSV by Layer/AddLayer/AddDelimtedTextLayer with selecting "No Geometry"

However, after I join the CSV to the shapefile, and go to Style/Graduate and classify, all the values come up as 0. It happens for each of the 5 values I have on my CSV file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found out the problem, I didn't double check the shapefile I was downloading... I got one for Census Blocks instead of the one for Census tracks :(